Prove that $\mathbb{P}(\max _{1 \leq m \leq n}|S_{m}| \leq x) \leq \frac{(x+K)^2 }{\rm{Var}(S_{n})}$
The problem is from the book of Durret: Probability theory and examples, Exercise 5.4.4.
Suppose that $\xi_m$ are independent,
$\mathbb{E} \xi_m=0$,  $\mathbb{E} \xi_m^2=\sigma_m^2$, and $|\xi_m|\leq K$.
Denote $S_n=\xi_1+\cdots+\xi_n$, $s_n^2=\sigma_1^2+\cdots+\sigma_n^2$.
Prove that
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\max _{1 \leq m \leq n}|S_{m}| \leq x \right) \leq \frac{(x+K)^{2}}{\operatorname{var}(S_{n})}.$$
There is a hint: $S_n^2-s_n^2$ is a martingale, so $S_n^2$ is a submartingale, we have the following theorem:
Theorem 5.4.1. If $X_n$ is a submartingale and $N$ is a stopping time with $P(N \leq
k) = 1$ then
$$\mathbb{E}X_0 \le \mathbb{E}X_N \le \mathbb{E}X_k.$$
I have no idea and I don't know how the use the stopping time, any comments will be appreciated!

Note $V[S_n]=s_n^2$. Let $\tau_x=\inf\{n:|S_n|>x\}$. By definition and assumption on the increments being bounded, $S_{\tau_x\wedge n}^2\leq (x+K)^2$ a.s. By optional stopping, $E[S_{\tau_x\wedge n}^2-s_{ \tau_x \wedge n}^2]=0$ so $E[s_{\tau_x\wedge n}^2]=E[S_{\tau_x\wedge n}^2]\leq (x+K)^2$. We then have $E[s_n^2\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau_x>n\}}]\leq E[s_{ \tau_x \wedge n}^2]\leq (x+K)^2$ and we conclude since then $P(\tau_x>n)\leq \frac{(x+K)^2}{s_n^2}$.

Thanks for comment, so do we have to use the  optional stopping theorem? Because another answer also use the same theorem, and I cant solve the problem just through theorem 5.4.1.

@Gangmen you can find the solution by (apparently) Durrett himself here.
